# Dynamic photo gallery in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to make a dynamic photo gallery in my iPhone application.All images in photo gallery come from server.Can anybody guide me how i can do it. Thanks.

Comment: You want to load images from a server?  There must be at least a few dozen if not hundreds of books, websites, apple documentation, blogs, examples on Github, etc. to do this. This isn't a tutorial site. Why don't you try reading some documentation first. Then try to actually implement it and if you get stuck somewhere, come back and ask for specific help.

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): *Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Three20` Framework, Which provides all photo library UI.
You can use same for pull images from local as well from server too.